# Admob ad not showing on adview

Tags: android, admob, adview

I am trying to put an adview to my app. I have put an adview on xml and is as follows

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>       
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"      
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"   
android:layout_width="match_parent"   
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >          

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />    
</ScrollView>

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ScrollView1"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6045707126584551/3116181621"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

and here is the code that i implemented in  order to initialize adview in java. This code is supposed to load the ads.

---

```
 public class SingleContactActivity extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
static final String ID = "id";
static final String POS = "position";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(ID);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
     // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("479004f857d93000").build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest); 
}
}
```

---

The ad is not loading on the device when i try it. Any hint or help would be much appriciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any blank view in you layout in bottom of the screen ?

Comment: How long ago did you create the ad campaign that should be shown? Because if I remember correctly, it takes about 24 hours until the adview will be filled. That means you will only see demo ads on the test device you specified. So verify the test device number is correct.

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: Why do you set the adview's width to "match_parent". Shouldn't it be: android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score -4):

Oh i found the solutions. It was my first time using adview so got a little confusing.

Comment: And what was the solution?

Comment: you may double check that you added answer already here, you could post the real answer instead of let us know that you just solved it. @SarojMjn